# Adding relevant categories to related post

Tags: categories

So, let say you have a post under a category called "computer." Within the page, you have related posts which are under the same `computer` category.

However, this does not include posts under a relevant category such as `computers`.

Because these are two different categories but very pretty much the same thing, I want to include these relevant categories together.

How can I link one category to another, even manually?

Thanks

Comment: Make computers as subcategory?

Comment: I see. So, have the `computers` as parent category and `computer`subcategory. That could work. I will do some more planning on this with this. Thanks Manoj! =)

Comment: Yes anyway around will work fine :) But you need to check both of them while creating posts.